# How to drop EOF from Enumerator

Tags: playframework, loops

I want to concatenate two `Enumerator`s. The problem is that `>>>` and `andThen` don't work if the first has an `EOF`.

I suppose I should drop the `EOF`, but I don't know how to cleanly do this.

I imagine there is a common, idiomatic way to do this. What is it?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of dropping EOF after from Iteratee A to concatenate with Iteratee B, I would split A, to have AwithoutEOF and A (which just concatenate AwithoutEOF with EOF). Then B can be concatenate with the right AwithoutEOF.

Comment: Make it doesn't have the EOF chunk in AwithoutEOF, re-declare A by concatenating the EOF.

Comment: Why down vote? This approach doesn't solve the issue in the expected way, as this way is not technically appropriate, but it does solve it.

Comment: (I did not downvote.) You misunderstand. I *have* an `Enumerator` with EOF, and I need to remove it. Saying don't have the EOF in it to start with is not solving the posed problem.

Comment: Wanting to solve the wrong problem due to granularity issue in original design is not the right way for me. Fixing original design to have right granularity with iteratee so that they are composable without tricks (removing after some element instead of just adding it in the right time) is the way I would go. Good luck.

Comment: I am using `Enumerator.fromFile`. Is that not a good approach?